# How to get image id from listVIew

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview

I have listView with 2 TextViews and 1 ImageView . I use custom adapter (ArrayAdapter and "Data" class) everything working as expected.

The problem is that I need to retrive somehow image resource or id from listView, so i can use it elsewhere in code...

I can get the Strings from Textviews like this below but not ImageView

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> MyListAdapter, View view, int position, long id) {

            TextView names = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.namesTV);
            TextView desc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.descTV);

            String names = names.getText().toString();
            String desc = desc.getText().toString();      //this works fine

            ImageView imageV = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageIV);

            // i tried 
            int image  = imageV.getID;  //or somthing .. but not working
        }
    }
```

So how to get that image id from ImageView selected onItemClick in ListView?

Comment: `imageV.getId()` returns the same of your `R.id.imageIV`. You are asking about Resource ID of the Image? Like `R.drawable.image`?

Comment: yes Resource id like R.drawable...

Comment: `setTag()/getTag()` is a solution, but ideally you find the correct image by `int position`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that I need to retrieve somehow image resource or id
>   from listView

To get image resource id which is currently available in clicked row do following:

**1.** Save resource id using `setTag` method in `getView` just after setting image for ImageView:

```
imageView.setTag(R.drwable.<image name>);
```

**2.** Now in `onItemClick` use `getTag` to get resource id:

```
ImageView imageV = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageIV);
int image  = Integer.parseInt(imageV.getTag().toString());
```

Comment: Ty for your help, do I need to setTag on every image i use?

Comment: @user2722931: Yes, `imageView.setTag(R.drwable.<image name>);` line just after line where setting image for ImageView in getView method

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **setTag()**/**getTag()**

Please reference the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922345/how-can-i-find-which-image-is-set-in-imageview-from-my-drawable)